# Adjust Javascript function for Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a JS function that opens pop ups by changing the width in CSS from 0 to a set number.
My aim is to set the width to be 33vw on desktop screens but 100vw on mobile, so that is it responsive.

Here's what I tried after some research on SO:

```
function openNav() {
  if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) && (window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight) ){
    document.getElementById("Nav").style.width = "100%";
  }
  document.getElementById("Nav").style.width = "33%";
  $('body').addClass('stop-scrolling')
}
```

I'm not vey advanced on JS but I feel as if I'm close and potentially just missing an ELSE statement? But I have no idea how to implement it.

If anyone could help me out and tell me what I'm doing wrong/missing, that would be great!

Thanks in advance, and if you need anything else please let me know!

Comment: you'd probably be better off creating a responsive design using CSS

Comment: Use a media query for this. Client sniffing is extremely hard to maintain and widely considered bad practice.

Comment: For example my mobile phone is a Jolla phone (which your JS would miss - a media query wouldn't).

Comment: @ADyson, How would I transfer this to CSS? what's the 'on click' version of :hover? Am I right in thinking I'd do:
button:active popup{
  width 33%;
}
and the same inside my media queries with different widths?

Comment: the whole point of responsiveness is that it happens automatically without the user having to click on anything to make it work. The page (and the elements within it) will just size itself appropriately without being asked to. But if you want to set a style which only applies to something which is currently being clicked on, then yes you'd use :active. And you'd set the value differently for each media query where you need to vary it (e.g. to have a different width for mobile / desktop / tablet). Not sure why you'd want to alter a button's width only when being clicked, though?

Comment: @ADyson Sorry, I confused you, I was trying to explain the CSS I'd use; 
So when the button is clicked, set the width of the pop up.
Not the width of the button :)

Comment: you don't need to wait for the click to set the width of the pop-up, you can pre-define it (as a set value or a %) for each separate width range (specified by your media queries) you want to support. The browser will do the rest. Seriously, take a responsive design tutorial, and it'll all become clear.

Comment: I understand the responsive design, what I'm saying is before the button is clicked the 'pop up' has it's width set to 0; so it is hidden from the main page, then on click it's width will either be 100vw or 33vw depending on device, I wasn't aware there was a CSS only method to achieve this

Comment: Instead of using the width to hide the popup, you should use its display property, that's the normal way. So the JS would just be used to show or hide the popup when clicks happen (by setting the display property) and the width is handled by CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're actually just missing an else statement - the way you have it right now, you're first checking if you're on a mobile Device (and if you're in Portrait mode!) and then, regardless of the outcome, you're overwriting the nav width with the 33%.

This tiny little fix should do it:

```
function openNav() {
    if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) && (window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight) ){
        document.getElementById("Nav").style.width = "100%";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("Nav").style.width = "33%";
        $('body').addClass('stop-scrolling');
    }
}
```

Edit:
As some people commented under your question, a CSS media query is probably the more elegant solution, but I wanted to let you that you were indeed rather close to do what you intended :)